# Tabulator update column position programmatically?

Tags: tabulator

Is it possible to update column position with Tabulator?
Or is there a way to do it?
Apparently there is no function to do it.

Answer (score 2):

A moveColumn function will be coming in the 4.2 release next week.

In the mean time you can easily change the order of columns in the table by calling the ***deleteColumn*** function and then the ***addColumn*** function.

```
//remove column
table.deleteColumn("age");

//add column elsewhere in the table after the name column
table.addColumn({title:"Age", field:"age"}, "name");
```

or by changing the column definition array and resubmitting it using the ***setColumns*** function

```
//define new column layout
var columns = [
    {title:"Name", field:"name"},
    {title:"Age", field:"age"},
    {title:"Gender", field:"gender"},
]

//replace all columns
table.setColumns(columns);
```

Full documentation on these features can be found in the [Columns Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/columns)

Comment: And is there any way to disable the column move for specific column ?

Comment: Nope. Because you could move other columns around it so all it would do it make for a bad user experience. You can use frozen columns if you want to fix a column in place